# Problems with Jquery tablesorter (with sticky headers) and Jquery scroller

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, tablesorter, manos

I like tablesorter for what I have been able to do with it so far, mostly a lot of JS custom  coding and I like the Jquery scroller from manos.malihu.gr for its easy customization. While tablesorter does come with some scrolling functionality, it also refers to integration with other scroll bar plugin. For example:

> scroller_barWidth - Set the width (default is 17) of the scroll bar in
>   pixels. This will need to be changed if using a custom scroll bar
>   plugin.

I would like to know if integration of the manos scrollbar with tablesorter has been successfully tried? Specifically, I would like to know if and how the sticky header options of tablesorter interoperate with the content div of the scroller? Any other problems encountered or issues to be dealt with, would be helpful. I could get the tablesorted to work with the scroller but I could not get the headers to stay while scrolling as the table (with the header) is one element in the content from the scroller's view.

Any reference to a scroller that can be customized and works with tablesorter would be helpful too.

Comment: Did you try the [css3 sticky header widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-css-sticky-header.html)?

Comment: @Mottie, I will be revisiting that code next week. Got caught up in something else for now. Thanks for the comment. Will look into it and post my results. Integration with the manos.malihu.. scrollbar will be of help to others too.